# Call a javascript function on Double Clicking a Row in DataGrid View (asp)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, wpf, datagrid

I want to call a javascript function that will get the value of the cells of the double clicked row in the Data Grid View.
I have something like this :

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string js;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["ondblclick"] = calljavascript;
    }
}
```

Any hint on how I can implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is as simple, as adding a piece of javascript to the page:

```
<script type="text/ecmascript">
    function analyseRow(row) {
        var children = row.cells, l = children.length, i, values = [];
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            values.push(children[i].innerHTML);
        }
        alert(values);
    }
</script>
```

and adding a stringbased call to the javascript function in the RowDataBound event

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    string js;
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes["ondblclick"] = "analyseRow(this)";
    }
}
```

the this inside the javascript call, refers to the row that is being clicked. Inside the analyseRow, the cells of the row are checked, and added 1 by one inside a valueArray. Then it is up to you what you want to do with the values inside the array

Comment: yeah that works!!! thanks!!
can you give me an example conde on how can I assign each value to my var usoing getelementbyname??

Comment: I'm sorry, what would you like to do? I didn't really understand your question. You want to have to values back to C# or you want to use them for something inside your javascript?